# Distribution of a bootstrap sample from a given reference sample

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, bootstrap

Consider $n$ samples $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$, where each is normally distributed according to mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We use these samples to define our reference population.

Given a bootstrap sample from this reference population, i.e., $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$, we know that the mean $\bar{Y}$ has expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$.

Can we say anything more about the distribution of the samples underlying the bootstrap sample? e.g., is $Y_i$ also normally distributed according to mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Depending on the exact details, I would argue $\bar x$ and $s_x$ instead of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.